# how do i format restful webservice json output so each json object starts on a new line?

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, jersey

For some reason, one of my @GET methods automatically outputs my JSON data in the following format while both implementations are exactly identical. I want my other @GET method to format exactly like the output shown below.

get all doctors code:

```
@Path("/doctors")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Doctor> getAllDoctors() throws Exception{
    return dao.getAllDoctors();
}
```

get all patients code:

```
@Path("/patients")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Patient> getAllPatients() throws Exception{
    return dao.getAllPatients();
}
```

uniform output:

```
[{"specialty":"surgeon","sex":"male","experience":4,"salary":23232.66,"id":3,"firstName":"kobe","lastName":"bryant"},
{"specialty":"surgeon","sex":"male","experience":4,"salary":23232.66,"id":33,"firstName":"D","lastName":"bryant"},
{"specialty":"eyebrows","sex":"female","experience":1,"salary":1.0,"id":2,"firstName":"joan","lastName":"smith"},
{"specialty":"eyebrows","sex":"female","experience":1,"salary":1.0,"id":69,"firstName":"joan","lastName":"smith"}]
```

Comment: Why do you want that? JSON is JSON. It's supposed to be read by a computer, not by a human. So why do you care? Why not format it in the client, if that's really needed?

Comment: I guess it's just easier to read and this is a relatively small program, so it looks nicer on the eyes. Can you care to explain why my program does this? My "getALLDoctors()" method outputs each JSON object to a new line, but my second @GET method outputs everything randomly clustered together. While both methods are functioning perfectly fine, it's just annoying to see two different results from two identically implemented methods.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approach to do so:

- Globally in a ResponseFilter:

The idea is to override the response content body and make it pretty there.
Keep in mind Jersey serialize your object with Jackson internally.

- Directly in the class:

You will have to change the signature of the REST method to Response type. Then you will serialize your object manually via Jackson with the ObjectMapper.

The step to do once you will have your Json Obecjt is to prettify it. JacksonUtils have a method to do so.

I will suggest you to add a query string in order to know if you want to have a pretty output or not. That will be more suitable.

Let me know if you want a more detailed anserw.

Hope it helps,